# Recalculation next position (x and y) based on rotate to N degree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, rotation, image-rotation

I need to calculate the next position of the shape (X and Y) but don't have any idea how. I tried different solutions but all-time something went wrong. Maybe someone can help me, I need a tip how it calculates, for best understand I will add screenshots.

**Description:** I have the image of the map in the background. I drew the shape on the image. After that, I need to rotate the background to N degrees (N can be from 0 to 360) and recalculate new position for shape (X, Y)

**Parameters which I have:**

- The start position of shape X and Y
- N degrees value
- Width and height of the shape

Also, I have the width and height of the background (if it will be needed).

- Start position
  [image: 1]
- Rotated the background to 90 degrees
  [image: 2]
- Rotated the background to 90 degrees. Manually changed position of the shape X and Y can have some mistake
  [image: 3]

I need some algorithm to calculate a new position for shape, thanks for any help.

Comment: The rotation of your object is the same as the rotation of the background. How do you rotate it? Always around its centre?

Comment: @MOehm Yeah, the background all time rotate around the center and the rotation for the object always equals the background rotate for save position relative to map image

Comment: So if you express the coordinates of your object in relation to the centre of the background, you have your rotation, no?

Comment: @MOehm i have the rotation value but need to calculate new X and Y for the shape. For example, you can saw the start position of shape X = 350 and Y = 125(first screen) and expected position of the shape X = 412 and Y = 200(last screen). I think I missed explain details, but the shapes no rotate with the background and i need to calculate new position. Also in second screen is you can saw wath happen after rotate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have rotated the background around its centre **C** about an angle of θ. You want to apply the same rotation to the shape's point **P**.

A rotation of **P** about the origin can be achieved with:

*P* ′<sub>*x*</sub> = *P* <sub>*x*</sub> · cos *θ*
− *P* <sub>*y*</sub> · sin *θ*
     *P* ′<sub>*y*</sub> = *P* <sub>*x*</sub> · sin *θ*
+ *P* <sub>*y*</sub> · cos *θ*

A rotation about a point **C** can be achieved by moving **C** to the origin, rotating, then moving **C** back. So:

*P* ′<sub>*x*</sub>
= (*P* <sub>*x*</sub> − *C* <sub>*x*</sub>) · cos *θ*
− (*P* <sub>*y*</sub> − *C* <sub>*y*</sub>) · sin *θ*
+ *C* <sub>*x*</sub>
     *P* ′<sub>*y*</sub>
= (*P* <sub>*x*</sub> − *C* <sub>*x*</sub>) · sin *θ*
+ (*P* <sub>*y*</sub> − *C* <sub>*y*</sub>) · cos *θ*
+ *C* <sub>*y*</sub>

In JavaScript:

```
R.x = (P.x - C.x) * Math.cos(a) - (P.y - C.y) * Math.sin(a) + C.x
R.y = (P.x - C.x) * Math.sin(a) + (P.y - C.y) * Math.cos(a) + C.y
```

where *a* is the sngle in radians. This will rotate clockwise. If you change the signs on the two sin terms, the rotation will be anticlockwise.

You can do the rotation on each of the points of your polygon or on the shape's centre, in which case you must rotate the shape about its centre, too.